# Java store inventory

Tags: java

I have to create a java program that does the following:

receive the following string:

```
1&Refrigerado&1300&55000&223&-2
1&Norefrigerado&3000&20000&230&EEUU
2
```

The output:

```
***Inventario de productos***

       Producto Refrigerado - Código: 223
       costo: 55000 pesos
       cantidad: 1300
       temperatuta: -2 grados centígrados

       Producto Norefrigerado - Código: 230
       costo: 20000 pesos
       cantidad: 3000
       país: EEUU
```

after that, split the string when the & symbol appears.

after that, it must be sent to a function called "seleccionaropciones" where there will be a swich case, with different options.

this is the code of the main class called "Tienda".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Tienda {
    
       
    public static void seleccionaropciones(int opc, String nombre,String cantidad,String costo,String codigo,String temperatura){
        
            switch(opc){
                case 1:
                    if(nombre.equals("Refrigerado")){
                        Refrigerado usu = new Refrigerado(nombre, cantidad, costo, codigo, temperatura);
                        usu.mostrardatos();
                    }else{
                        NoRefrigerado a = new NoRefrigerado(temperatura, nombre, cantidad, costo, codigo, temperatura);
                        a.mostrardatosNo();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Mostrar datos");
                break;
               
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Adios A todos");
                break;
                
        }
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            //String s = "1&Norefrigerado&3000&20000&230&EEUU";
            String[] line = s.split("&");  
            int cod = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
            int size = line.length;
        
            if(size > 1){
                String nombre = line[1];
                String cantidad = line[2];
                String costo = line[3];
                String codigo = line[4];
                String temperatura = line[5];
                seleccionaropciones(cod,nombre,cantidad,costo,codigo,temperatura);
            }else{
                seleccionaropciones(cod,null,null,null,null,null);
            }
            
       /*
        System.out.println("nombre: " + nombre + "-" + "Código: " + codigo);
        System.out.println("costo: " + costo);
        System.out.println("cantidad: " + cantidad);
        System.out.println("temperatura: " + temperatura + " grados centígrados");
      */
         
    }
    
}
```

in case 1: you must save the data entered by console, in the product class that inherits two more classes (Refrigerado and NoRefrigerado).

in case 2: display the saved data

in case 3: exit

product code:

```
public class Producto {
    
    public String refrigerado;
    public String cantidad;
    public String costo;
    public String codigo;
    public String temperatura;

    
    public Producto(String refrigerado, String cantidad, String costo, String codigo, String temperatura) {
        this.refrigerado = refrigerado;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.costo = costo;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
  
    }

}
```

code Refrigerado:

```
public class Refrigerado extends Producto{
    
    public String temperatura;

    public Refrigerado(String refrigerado, String cantidad, String costo, String codigo, String temperatura) {
        super(refrigerado, cantidad, costo, codigo, temperatura);
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
    }

    public void mostrardatos(){
        System.out.println("nombre: " + refrigerado + " - " + "Código: " + codigo);
        System.out.println("costo: " + costo);
        System.out.println("cantidad: " + cantidad);
        System.out.println("temperatura: " + temperatura + " grados centígrados"); 
    }
```

code NoRefrigerado:

```
public class NoRefrigerado extends Producto {
    
   public String pais;

    public NoRefrigerado(String pais, String refrigerado, String cantidad, String costo, String codigo, String temperatura) {
        super(refrigerado, cantidad, costo, codigo, temperatura);
        this.pais = pais;
    }


     public void mostrardatosNo(){
        System.out.println("nombre: " + refrigerado + " - " + "Código: " + codigo);
        System.out.println("costo: " + costo);
        System.out.println("cantidad: " + cantidad);
        System.out.println("pais: " + pais); 
    }
   
}
```

This is the UML:

[image]

my question is the following.

How do I save the products, and how can I display them according to the required output.

Also, how do I repeat the program so that several products can be entered and then displayed.

(in "Refrigerated" the temperature of the product must be shown when "Refrigerado" appears and in "Norefrigerated" it shows the pias).

I hope I have made myself understood, and I apologize that the post was a little long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to store things, use a `List<Producto>`

Comment: You have not implemented the toString() methods you have in the UML diagram.
Replace `public void mostrardatosNo(){` with 
`@Override public String toString() {`
Things that are the same between the to classes can go into the Protocto class, and you do not need to save temperatura in the Producto class. (It's not in the UML)

For more info about toString() see https://www.journaldev.com/18578/java-tostring-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change and add a few things in order to achieve what you want.

Your `UML` shows that the `Producto` class have no `temperatura` field, Also rename the field `refrigerado` to `nombre` as stated in the UML. So remove it and fix the constructor:

```java
public class Producto {

    public String nombre;
    public String cantidad;
    public String costo;
    public String codigo;


    public Producto(String nombre, String cantidad, String costo, String codigo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.costo = costo;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
}
```

Fix the corresponding field and constructor call in `Refrigerado` and `NoRefrigerado` and change their method `mostrardatos()` and `mostrardatosNo()` to the required `toString()`. The corresponding `toStirng()` methods are implemented according to your output requirement.

NoRefrigerado.java

```java
public class NoRefrigerado extends Producto {

    public String pais;

    public NoRefrigerado(String pais, String refrigerado, String cantidad, String costo, String codigo) {
        super(refrigerado, cantidad, costo, codigo);
        this.pais = pais;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\t\tProducto " + nombre + " - " + "Código: " + codigo + "\n" +
        "\t\tcosto: " + costo + " pesos" + "\n" +
        "\t\tcantidad: " + cantidad + "\n" +
        "\t\tpais: " + pais + "\n";

    }

}
```

Refrigerado.java

```java
public class Refrigerado extends Producto {

    public String temperatura;

    public Refrigerado(String nombre, String cantidad, String costo, String codigo, String temperatura) {
        super(nombre, cantidad, costo, codigo);
        this.temperatura = temperatura;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\t\tProducto " + nombre + " - " + "Código: " + codigo + "\n" +
        "\t\tcosto: " + costo + " pesos" + "\n" +
        "\t\tcantidad: " + cantidad  + "\n" +
        "\t\ttemperatura: " + temperatura + " grados centígrados"  + "\n";
    }
}
```

Finally implement the main() in following manner to run infinitely and exit only when the user wants to exit, by entering 3. Also, to save the products which are given as input by the user, you can keep a List and add that whenever a product is detected.

Let's look at the main class `Tienda.java`:

```java
public class Tienda {

    private static List<Producto> products = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            String s = sc.nextLine();
            //String s = "1&Norefrigerado&3000&20000&230&EEUU";
            String[] line = s.split("&");
            int cod = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
            int size = line.length;

            if (size > 1) {
                String nombre = line[1];
                String cantidad = line[2];
                String costo = line[3];
                String codigo = line[4];
                String temperatura = line[5];
                seleccionaropciones(cod, nombre, cantidad, costo, codigo, temperatura);
            } else {
                seleccionaropciones(cod, null, null, null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void seleccionaropciones(int opc, String nombre, String cantidad, String costo, String codigo, String temperatura) {

        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                if (nombre.equals("Refrigerado")) {
                    Refrigerado usu = new Refrigerado(nombre, cantidad, costo, codigo, temperatura);
                    products.add(usu);
                } else {
                    NoRefrigerado a = new NoRefrigerado(temperatura, nombre, cantidad, costo, codigo);
                    products.add(a);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("***Inventario de productos***\n");
                for (Producto producto : products) {
                    System.out.println(producto);
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Adios A todos");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Now proceed with the inputs and you'll get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I had already run out of ideas on how to do it. 

I reiterate Thank you very much.